# How can I create URLs that only include the query string?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I want to use URL rewriting in apache web server to have these types of URLs:

```
www.mysite.com/user.php?id=user1
www.mysite.com/user.php?id=user2
www.mysite.com/user.php?id=me
www.mysite.com/user.php?id=you
www.mysite.com/user.php?id=every_thing
```

be changed to

```
www.mysite.com/user1
www.mysite.com/every_thing
```

and

```
www.mysite.com/user1/
```

I have tried this in my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) user.php?id=$1
```

It didn't work. What is the problem?

And I should say I have other directories like:

```
www.mysite.com/images/
www.mysite.com/videos/
```

So how can I also make it so it doesn't conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+user\.php\?id=(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /user.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No my users are different!!! it's not user1 , user2 , ...  . it's all possible usernames with numbers , characters and _ .

Comment: thanks. it works. how can i inactive(redirect) this addresses: "site.com/user/" to this "site.com/user" ???! because images doesn't load because of new address!

Comment: thanks veeery much anubhava. it works well! but the main address is still accessible !!! is it possible to inactive that?

Comment: No, the main address is still accessible and the new one makes error:"This webpage has a redirect loop"

Comment: loop problem solved but main address is accessible . sorry :(

Comment: ah there was typo, fixed. try again

Answer (score 0):

Adapted from wordpress's .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(user\d) /user.php?id=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: which url did it 404 for?